# Why Zero to the Power Zero Does NOT Throw Math Domain Error in Exponentiation?

Tags: python, numpy, math, default

Although I make frequent good use of it, I came to realize that the following might be an issue on a larger projects.

In many coding languages, including python,

```
0**0
```

returns 1, and does not throw a value error. This may not seem all that significant at first look, but once logarithms come into the picture it becomes sort of an issue. An avoidable issue but annoying nonetheless.

Consider this

```
from math import log
foo = 0 * log(0)
bar = log(0**0)
```

Now, mathematically, `foo` and `bar` are equivalent, while for python, the value of `bar` is 0 whereas `foo` throws a `MathDomainError`

Similarly, if you import `log` from `numpy`, `foo` will be `nan` whereas `bar` will be 0.

Granted that for most applications 0 log(0) is just zero, but strictly speaking in math terms, it is undefined and should be specially handled by the programmer.

My question is, is there a good reason why `0**0 = 1` in python or is this just an oversight.

Either way, it doesn’t really matter but something that can be annoying at times.

Comment: There's [a Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_to_the_power_of_zero) that explains why `0**0` could be 1.

Comment: You're coming at exponents from a continuous perspective. From a discrete perspective, 1 is the natural value for 0**0.

Comment: I see, so it's just a convention that people are aware of. I should note that 0.0**0.0 also returns 1. I can totally live with this caveat although I was a bit surprised when 0*log(0) threw an error. I guess this happens due to the order of evaluation (log is evaluated before the 0* that proceeds it)

Comment: 0*log(0) is not a single operation: log(0) must be computed first, independently. That's the part that raises the error

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake lies in "Mathematically foo and bar are equivalent". They are not. Log(0) is undefined, and hence doesn't follow the rule a log(b)=log(b^a).